Existence of limit of Bessel function of the second kind with integer order
The second kind of the Bessel function of integer-order is given as
$$
Y_n(x)=\lim_{\nu\to n}\frac{J_\nu(x)\cos(\nu\pi)-J_{-\nu}(x)}{\sin(\nu\pi)}
$$
Before using the L'Hôpital's rule, one should first prove that such a limit exists. However I can't find any.
How to prove that this limit exists?

You don't have to show that the limit of $f/g$ exists, that is a consequence of L'Hôpital's rule if the limit of $f'/g'$ exists. The derivative of $J_\nu$ wrt order leads to $Y_\nu$, so the above is $Y_n = \lim_{\nu\to n}Y_\nu$.

No. In proving L'Hôpital's rule, you have to use the assumption that $f/g$ has a limit. There are counterexamples. For example, $f(x)=x+\sin(x)\cos(x)$ and $g(x)=f(x)\exp(\sin(x))$. As $x\to\infty$, $f'/g'=0$ but there is no limit for $f/g$.

The full statement for $x\to c$ also requires $g'\ne0$ for all $x$ in some open interval of which $c$ is an accumulation point. For your example, $g'(x)\propto\cos(x)$ which is $0$ in any where $\infty$ is an accumulation point.

Some discussion in the answers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922502/can-we-use-l-hospital-to-prove-whether-limit-exists-or-not#:~:text=Yes%2C%20that%20is%20what%20L,)g(x)%20exists.

$g'=f'\exp(\sin x)+f(\exp(\sin x))'$. There is a term $x(\exp(\sin x))'$ in $g'$. Therefore $g'\ne0$ as $x\to\infty$.

$f'=1+\cos^2x-\sin^2x=2\cos^2x$ so $g'=(2\cos^2x + f\cos x)e^{\sin x}\propto\cos x$.

Note that I'm not saying $g'\to 0$, but that for any open interval $(R,\infty)$, $g'=0$ for at least one point in that interval so fails the conditions for L'Hôpital's rule (actually infinitely many points).

Anyway, there are some conditions to use L'Hôpital's rule.

Exactly, and for your original equation, $g=\sin(\nu\pi)$, $g'=\pi\cos(\nu\pi)$, so for every integer $n$, there are intervals $\nu\in(n-\epsilon,n+\epsilon)$ where the are no zeros of $g'$.
